# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating a student evaluation form in a repeater that should submit the evaluation responses and update the SQL database, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. I'm coding in ASP.Net using VB.

Here's my code:
Student.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

    <asp:Wizard ID="StudentEvaluationWizard" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Course">
                <asp:GridView ID="CourseView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="SectionID" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EnrollmentID" HeaderText="EnrollmentID" 
                            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EnrollmentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" 
                            SortExpression="StudentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionID" HeaderText="SectionID" 
                            SortExpression="SectionID" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" HeaderText="Section" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Section.Course.Name") %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:WizardStep>

            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Evaluation">
                <asp:Repeater ID="EvalRepeater" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="EvaluationQuestions">
                <HeaderTemplate><caption><asp:Label ID="EvaluationTitle" runat="server" Text='<%Eval("Evaluation.Evaluation1.") %>' /><caption></HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                   <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Questions" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question1") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%--Move outside of table to make edits--%>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Question" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="StudentComment" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                   <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit Evaluation" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>

    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="CourseSelect" runat="server" ContextTypeName="EvaluationDAL.Model.EvaluationDataDataContext"
        EntityTypeName="Enrollment" TableName="Enrollments" Where="StudentID == @StudentID">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="StudentID" Name="StudentID" SessionField="StudentID"
                Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>

    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="EvaluationQuestions" runat="server" ContextTypeName="EvaluationDAL.Model.EvaluationDataDataContext"
        EntityTypeName="" TableName="Questions" 
        Where="EvaluationID == Convert.ToInt32(@EvaluationID)">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="EvaluationID" SessionField="EvaluationID" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Student.aspx.vb (Submit button with the error)

```
 Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click

        Dim sr As New StudentEvaluation
        sr.SectionID = EvaluationGlobal.SectionID
        sr.EvaluationDate = DateAndTime.Now


        'Create a new evaluation object
        Dim eval As New StudentEvaluation


        For Each row As RepeaterItem In EvalRepeater.Items
            'Get the question
            Dim questionID As Label = CType(row.FindControl("QuestionID"), Label)
            Dim question1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(question1)

            eval.Comments = Convert.ToInt32(row.FindControl("Comments"))

            'Find radio button list with the name Question and convert to radio button list
            Dim rank As RadioButtonList = CType(row.FindControl("Question"), RadioButtonList)

            'Get the infomation if the area is not empty
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rank.SelectedValue) Then
                Dim ser As New StudentEvaluationResponse
                ser.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(row.FindControl("QuestionID"))
                ser.Answer = Convert.ToInt16(row.FindControl("Question"))

                Dim questionRank As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(rank.SelectedValue)
                Dim studentComment As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("StudentComment"), TextBox)
                Dim comment As String = studentComment.Text
                eval.StudentEvaluationResponses.Add(ser)

            End If
        Next
        If eval.StudentEvaluationResponses.Count > 0 Then
            eval.Insert()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I'm completely lost on how to fix this. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong to start with:

```
Dim question1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(question1)
```

I *suspect* you actually mean:

```
Dim question1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(questionID.Text)
```

Likewise I suspect these:

```
ser.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(row.FindControl("QuestionID"))
ser.Answer = Convert.ToInt16(row.FindControl("Question"))
```

should use the `Text` property:

```
ser.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(CType(row.FindControl("QuestionID"), Label).Text)
ser.Answer = Convert.ToInt16(CType(row.FindControl("Question"), RadioButton).Text)
```

That way you're trying to convert the text of the control, not the control itself.

Comment: The QuestionID is fixed but now the Answer section is getting an error. I think this is because it's a radio button list and not a label. Should I change it to this:
ser.Answer = Convert.ToInt16(CType(row.FindControl("Question"), RadioButton)

Comment: @DaniMoss: You still need to use a property of the RadioButton, not just the RadioButton itself. It's not clear which property you want to use though. Are you sure you don't mean RadioButtonList instead of RadioButton?

Comment: So should the code read:
ser.Answer = Convert.ToInt16(CType(row.FindControl("Question"), Checked)RadioButton)

Comment: @DaniMoss: No, it shouldn't. At this point you should stop just guessing with syntax, and *understand* what the code in my answer does. You want to find the control, cast it (with CType) to the appropriate type (e.g. RadioButton, RadioButtonList, whatever), extract the relevant text from the control, then parse that with Convert.ToInt16. You may well find it easiest to do this in several separate statements - it would certainly make it simpler to debug through the code.

Comment: I was able to get the error fixed. I'm now getting a date/time error that I will hopefully be able to figure out. Thanks for your help! :)